# How to get full worker output in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

How do I view / download the complete stderr output from a worker in Apache Spark, deployed in cluster mode?

I've deployed a program with `spark-submit --deploy-mode cluter foo.jar`, and a worker crashed.  To investigate, I go to `localhost:8081` and access the worker's log (stderr in particular), but then it shows me only the bottom of the file, and I have to click the "Load More" button a hundred times to scroll up to the first error -- clearly, I shouldn't have to do that.  Is there a way to download the whole stderr output, or to redirect it to a known location?  Which part of Spark's documentation gives me this kind of information?

Answer (score 0):

Get the Application Id of your spark job from yarn URL OR after submitting spark job you will get spark Application Id.

Then use the below command in YARN CLI to view the yarn logs from your edge/gateway node. for more details about YARN CLI refer this link [click here](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/data-operating-system/content/use_the_yarn_cli_to_view_logs_for_running_applications.html)

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Application ID> -log_files stderr
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm using the standalone manager, not YARN.